# Proof of a continuous function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I would like to know how tho prove or disprove the following:

Prove the following statement:

Every continuous function $f:[a,b] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ (with $a < b$) is (from above) bounded.

I have to use the opposite position of that statement by using the Weierstrass Interval technique for an appropriate sequence.

I have no idea where to begin and to end...Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: You may show that $f([a, b])$ is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ unbounded.

For $n=1$, we have $x_1$ s.t. $f(x_1)>1$.

For $n=2$, we have $x_2$ s.t. $f(x_2)>2$.

...

For each $n$, we have $x_n$ s.t. $f(x_n)>n$.

Try again from here.